# How to specify caps for Gstreamer in Rust?

Tags: rust, gstreamer

When I do:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! videoconvert ! waylandink
```

I get a video stream and from `gst-device-monitor-1.0` I can say it's `video/x-raw`

When I do:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! video/x-h264 ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! waylandink
```

I get the encoded stream instead of the raw one.

My question is: how can I specify the caps `video/x-h264` for my source element in Rust?
I can use the `set-property` method to change the width, height, or framerate but I can't find how to change from raw to h264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax

```
! caps !
```

in `gst-launch` automatically creates a [capsfilter](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/coreelements/capsfilter.html?gi-language=c) element.

In your Rust code, you would create the `capsfilter` element explicitly.

Comment: I read the documentation and found that the element has the property "caps" and by setting it to "video/x-h264" it works. Thanks for your answer I was not aware it was an element but it makes sense.